# AWS Application load balancer throwing 502

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I am currently learning about AWS and I have a single EC2 instance running with a nodejs server on port 3000, an `Application load balancer` with SSL setup that listen on port `80` and `443` (http & https). When I make requests to the http route it returns back the successful health check message. But when I try to access my api via the https method, I get a `502 Error`. I googled around and read some articles and they pointed out that the nodejs server `keepAliveTimeout` and `headersTimeout` should be higher than the timeout option of the ALB. I tried that and it didn't work. I also tried to set the `max-http-header-value` to `16384`, I also tried to check the access logs for the load balancer on my S3 bucket and the logs just showed that I am getting a 502 error and nothing more. What could be the issue? Because I have tried all solutions that presented but they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to check is that your server is responding to requests. Try connecting to port 3000 on the server, either from the server itself (eg `curl localhost:3000`) or from outside the server (which will require the Security Group to permit access to port 3000).

Once you have confirm that the server is responding, configure Security Groups as:

- A Security Group on the Application Load Balancer (`ALB-SG`) that permits Inbound access on ports 80 and 443
- A Security Group on the Amazon EC2 instance (`App-SG`) that permits inbound access on port 3000 from `ALB-SG`

That is, `App-SG` should specifically refer to `ALB-SG` in its Inbound rules.

Then, configure the Load Balancer to have a Target Group that points at port 3000 on the app server and provide it a URL for the Health Check (that could simply be `/`).

Then, connect to the Application Load Balancer and see whether you can access your app.

Answer (score 1):

The 443 listener needs to be pointed to port 80 on the ec2 instance

Comment: thanks for the reply. I created a target group to route 443 to HTTP port 80 even though my Nodejs server currently listens on Port 3000. But the health check returns back an `unhealthy` status.